# How do we use AWS/S3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, parse-server

I need some simple example to get started with AWS/S3 usage.

Here is the situation; an iOS app of mine has been transfered from Parse.com to Parse-Server / Heroku.
All is working fine, but I will at some point need file storage for images or sound files.
I have already followed [this](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Configuring-File-Adapters#configuring-s3adapter) and configured an S3Adapter.

My problem now is : "How to use it?"

I would like to find some sample code using this S3Adapter that I just configured to save something and retrieve it.

Comment: Hey, just a quick heads up -- asking for examples in this way usually causes questions to get closed with 'asking for tutorials/off-site resources' close reason.  Could you take a look at some of [these code snippets for 'parse s3adapter' on github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=parse+s3adapter&type=Code&ref=searchresults) and revise the question to include your own work-in-progress code snippet that we can help improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already configured S3 in your parse server and provide all the relevant details like bucket, keys etc. the next thing is to test it and check that parse really store your files on S3 and not on GridStore (which is the default).

In order to test it please go through the following steps:

1. Open your **index.js** file which located under the root folder of your parse server project and check that your files adapter is S3. It should look something like this (from parse server wiki):

```js
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'APPLICATION_ID',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'MASTER_KEY',
  ...
  filesAdapter: new S3Adapter(
    "S3_ACCESS_KEY",
    "S3_SECRET_KEY",
    "S3_BUCKET", {
      directAccess: true
    }
  ),
  ...
});
```

2. Next you need to save some file in your iOS client side. You need to create a new PFFile and just call the **saveInBackground** method in order to save this file. before saving the file parse-server will check if you provide custom files adapter and if you did it will try to use it, if not it will go to the default (GridStore on MongoDB). So your iOS code should look like the following:

**objective c**

```js
    NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    PFFile * imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName: @"image.png"
      data: imageData
    ];
    [imageFile saveInBackground];
```

**swift**

```js
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
let imageFile = PFFile(name:"image.png", data:imageData)
imageFile.saveInBackground()
```

After the file is being saved you can go to your Bucket in AWS and check if the file has been added there.

Hope it helps. If you need more info please let me know.

Comment: Just a small question, if I use your code to save an image, with the default settings (i.e. GridStoreAdapter and not S3Adapter) as a simple test. Where can I check that my file has been correctly uploaded? I just tried and it may have worked (at least there was no crash), but I don't know where to check.

Comment: You can check it inside your MongoDB but it's better to check it with parse-dashboard (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard) because it much more simple to do it this way. Parse-Dashboard allows you to see all your data inside your MongoDB in a very simple and easy way

Comment: Well, I looked at that, but didn't notice anything. Where exactly (in MongoDB or parse-dashboard) should I see something?

Comment: Inside the class where you store the file you can see it . In order to really see the file itself you must store it inside a parse object

Comment: I see. Since I just performed (as a test) a saveInBackground on a PFFile (just following your code) without putting it in any class, it may have not worked then.

Comment: After experimenting a bit more I can see indeed something like "imgField": "1a.......914....233..._image.png", in my class, as you said. But is there a way that I can see the file (on the server), not only the file name in a class record?

Comment: I have been able to make things work (i.e. writing a .png file to the server and recovering it, within my iOS app) using GridStoreAdapter. Unfortunately when I want to use S3Adapter, I still have problems. I get the following error message: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."

Comment: I had forgotten the line :var S3Adapter = require('parse-server').S3Adapter;
Now it works!